# How to seperate the columns when counting in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, count

How do I count the number of countries separately into different columns using queries in SQL?

All the countries in column:

```
   Countries   
   US   
   Spain   
   Germany   
   US   
   Mexico
```

The country totals to display as:

Mexico 1
USA 2
Spain 1
Germany 1

I'm trying to use a query like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(Country) AS 'Mexico', COUNT(Country) AS 'USA', COUNT(Country) AS 'Spain', COUNT(Country) AS 'Germany'
FROM Customers
WHERE Country='Mexico' AND Country='US' AND Country='Spain' AND Country='Germany';
```

The result displayed as:

Mexico 0
USA 0
Spain 0
Germany 0

Anyone help me out here?

Comment: Use condition aggregation.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select sum(case when country = 'Mexico' then 1 else 0 end) as mexico,
       sum(case when country = 'USA' then 1 else 0 end) as usa,
       sum(case when country = 'Spain' then 1 else 0 end) as spain,
       sum(case when country = 'German' then 1 else 0 end) as german        
from Customers;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try:

```sql
Select distinct (Countries) as Country_Names, count(Countries) as Count_of_countries from Customers
```

Comment: This won't work, due to the omission of `Countries` from the `GROUP BY`. `DISTINCT` isn't a function, it's an operator. Though using `DISTINCT` with aggregation is normally a sign of a error as well.