# Pivot row data and count into columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I've got two columns of data as below:

| Client | Type |
| --- | --- |
| A | Pencil |
| A | Ruler |
| A | Pen |
| B | Pencil |
| B | Ruler |
| C | Pencil |
| C | Pen |

I want to pivot 'Type' and make them the columns and group by 'Client'. Result would look like below:

| Client | Count(Pencil) | Count(Ruler) | Count(Pen) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| B | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| C | 1 | 0 | 1 |

How can I achieve this on SQL Server?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, you can express this as:

```
select client,
       sum(case when type = 'Pencil' then 1 else 0 end) as pencil,
       sum(case when type = 'Ruler' then 1 else 0 end) as ruler,
       sum(case when type = 'Pen' then 1 else 0 end) as pen
from t
group by client;
```

Comment: Did you forget you posted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68793302/2029983) a few hours before this one again?

Answer (score 0):

Please see [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15) for reference.

```
SELECT Client, [Pencil], [Ruler], [Pen]
FROM  
(
  SELECT Client, Type
  FROM tableName
) AS SourceTable  
PIVOT  
(  
  count(Type)  
  FOR Type IN ([Pencil], [Ruler], [Pen])  
) AS PivotTable;
```